# Replace all non-word characters with a space

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex

```
[A-Za-z]
```

and a string, such as

> Hi! This is a string.

I want to replace all charcters that are not in the Regex with space.  So, I'll end up with

> Hi  This is a string

How is this done?

Comment: Is there some code you have tried and doesn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var cleaned = Regex.Replace(given, "[^A-Za-z]", " ");
```

Comment: Do I need the ^ at the front?  I'm not comparing against only the start of the string.  I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @SachinKainth:  `^` has two meanings -- _beginning of string_ when used outside of brackets (`[]`) and _not_ when used inside brackets.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Technically three meanings, if you enable multiline mode  =)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^A-Za-z]", " ");
```